# Android - using MediaCodec with byte array only

Tags: android, encode, android-mediacodec

I'm moving around  some samples of MediaCodec usage through the BigFlake and Grafika examples.

I cant find any example or way to create video without GLsurface as a buffer.

my app using customize byte array and send it to FFmpeg  library-which create and encode video file.
but i like to add support for 4.3/4.4 version with the media codec.

Is there any way to send a byte[] array to the Encoder ?
for example if i like to use onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame) ,from the camera.
I dont want to send it to the glsurface,just encode it as is.

Any idea?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to answer. The `MediaCodec` class has a `getInputBuffers` method that gives you a `ByteBuffer[]`, and a `dequeueInputBuffer` method that gives you an index of a buffer in that array that you should fill next (refer to [the `MediaCodec` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)). The `ByteBuffer` class, in turn, has a `put(byte[])` method.

Comment: See the buffer-to-buffer and buffer-to-surface tests in http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest .  They encode video from YUV buffers.  You have to convert the YUV data from the camera to a different color format before submitting it; see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q5 .  If your data is strictly from Camera without modification, it might be better to just modify how the frames are received from the camera.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Soory not yet,my  app spec was changed